# Posting Foursquare check-in to Facebook Timeline map programmatically?

Tags: foursquare, facebook-timeline

I am working on iOS / php / MySQL application, which uses Foursquare API, in order to post check-ins to Foursquare. I would also like to post these Foursquare check-ins to Facebook Timeline map. Basically, after clicking "Check-in" button, check-in should be posted to both Foursquare and Facebook. What is the  best way to do it? Please provide quick example. Appreciate it.

Note: I don't have "Log in with Facebook" functionality in my application, only "Log in with Foursquare"

Answer (score 0):

The [checkins/add](https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/checkins/add) endpoint has a `broadcast` parameter, which accepts the value `facebook`. If that parameter is provided, the check-in will be shared to Facebook, if possible. The user will have needed to connect their Facebook account with their Foursquare account, and granted Foursquare permission to post to their wall for this to work.